# Как отсортировать данные в List<T>, чтобы строки с числами были по возрастанию?

Tags: c#, сортировка, list

Есть список, в который мы грузим имена файлов из текущей директории

Пример файлов - `0.jpg`,`1.jpg`,`2.jpg` и т.д. Как отсортировать список по возрастанию? Одно дело если бы там были цифры. А когда в `list` содержит строковые данные-они сортируются некорректно. 0.jpg,1.jpg и **10.jpg**

[image]

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles("*.jpg"); //Getting Text files
string str = "";
foreach(FileInfo file in Files )
{
    list.Add(file.Name);

}
```

Comment: Поясните, чем вас не устроила сортировка строк из коробки?

Comment: Поправил.......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Насколько я понял из вашего описания, вас интересует "естественная" сортировка (natural sort), которая правильно отсортирует числа в строковом виде, например, "1, 2, 10, 20" вместо "1, 10, 2, 20". В Windows для этого есть встроенная функция `StrCmpLogical`. Чтобы воспользоваться ей для сортировки строк и файлов, вам понадобится реализовать интерфейс `IComparer<T>`.

```
[SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
internal static class NativeMethods
{
    [DllImport("shlwapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern int StrCmpLogicalW(string psz1, string psz2);
}

public sealed class NaturalStringComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    public int Compare(string a, string b)
    {
        return NativeMethods.StrCmpLogicalW(a, b);
    }
}

public sealed class NaturalFileInfoNameComparer : IComparer<FileInfo>
{
    public int Compare(FileInfo a, FileInfo b)
    {
        return NativeMethods.StrCmpLogicalW(a.Name, b.Name);
    }
}
```

Ну а дальше эти компареры можно передавать в любую сортирующую функцию. Так как у вас массив, то можно так:

```
Array.Sort(Files, new NaturalFileInfoNameComparer());
```

Answer (score 4):

Можно попробовать так:

```
list.Sort((x, y) =>
    {
        int ix, iy;
        return int.TryParse(x, out ix) && int.TryParse(y, out iy)
              ? ix.CompareTo(iy) : string.Compare(x, y);
    });
```

Или так:

```
public class NaturalSortComparer<T> : IComparer<string>, IDisposable
{
    private bool isAscending;

    public NaturalSortComparer(bool inAscendingOrder = true)
    {
        this.isAscending = inAscendingOrder;
    }

    #region IComparer<string> Members

    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion

    #region IComparer<string> Members

    int IComparer<string>.Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        if (x == y)
            return 0;

        string[] x1, y1;

        if (!table.TryGetValue(x, out x1))
        {
            x1 = Regex.Split(x.Replace(" ", ""), "([0-9]+)");
            table.Add(x, x1);
        }

        if (!table.TryGetValue(y, out y1))
        {
            y1 = Regex.Split(y.Replace(" ", ""), "([0-9]+)");
            table.Add(y, y1);
        }

        int returnVal;

        for (int i = 0; i < x1.Length && i < y1.Length; i++)
        {
            if (x1[i] != y1[i])
            {
                returnVal = PartCompare(x1[i], y1[i]);
                return isAscending ? returnVal : -returnVal;
            }
        }

        if (y1.Length > x1.Length)
        {
            returnVal = 1;
        }
        else if (x1.Length > y1.Length)
        { 
            returnVal = -1; 
        }
        else
        {
            returnVal = 0;
        }

        return isAscending ? returnVal : -returnVal;
    }

    private static int PartCompare(string left, string right)
    {
        int x, y;
        if (!int.TryParse(left, out x))
            return left.CompareTo(right);

        if (!int.TryParse(right, out y))
            return left.CompareTo(right);

        return x.CompareTo(y);
    }

    #endregion

    private Dictionary<string, string[]> table = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();

    public void Dispose()
    {
        table.Clear();
        table = null;
    }
}
```

Применение:

```
list.OrderBy(item => item, new NaturalSortComparer<string>()).ToList();
```