# как сделать натуральную сортировку в datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, сортировка, datagrid

VS2010 как сделать натуральную сортировку в datagrid согласно примеру в [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ff407126(v=vs.100).aspx).
Сортировка работает, но цифры сортирует как символы. Как исправить код?

---

```
ICollectionView cvTasks = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(dataGrid1.ItemsSource);
if (cvTasks != null && cvTasks.CanSort == true)
{
    cvTasks.SortDescriptions.Clear();
    cvTasks.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("ProjectName", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
    cvTasks.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Complete", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
    cvTasks.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("DueDate", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
}
```

Comment: Поясните на примере как вы хотите отсортировать цифры.

Comment: Покажите тип данных,которые у вас отображаются в DataGrid

Comment: В результате сортировки должно получиться: Task 1Task2 Task11

Comment: Нашел [такой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/467478/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2-listt-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%81-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E/467482#467482) вариант но как его прикрутить к своему примеру не понимаю пока(((